# opening other developer app require provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I cloned app from **bitbucket**. Everything went smoothly till I try to build it.
I got the error that I need a developer team, when I pick personal team I got two errors that i'm not able to handle myself, those are:

"Cannot create a Mac App Development provisioning profile for "com.username.appname".
Your development team, "user name", does not support the In-App Purchase and Maps capabilities."

"No profiles for 'com.username.appname' were found
**Xcode** couldn't find any Mac App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.username.appname'."

So far I was just making some simple apps by myself even though I had no team apps that were working fine at least on simulator. Now it seems be to 'eavy. 
If anyone could help me, it would be appreciated its not really a programming problem though closely connected to Xcode.

I got some idea that I need paid account but as I read some info its just to post app in app store though I don't know if it would solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, because the app specifies the in-App purchasing entitlement you must have a paid developer membership to create the provisioning profile

Comment: thank you, is it possible to remove this feather just to work on app? well i think its time for me 2 buy an account anyway